# Cannot find and create Qt Quick UI Project

Tags: windows, qt

I'm new to Qt Creator and reading the book Qt 5 Cadaques. It told me to create a Qt Quick UI Project which is in the Other Project category in the New Project window. However, I cannot find anything like that. Did I miss something while installing the IDE? [Here](http://s17.postimg.org/fcrq3uku7/Untitled.png) is the screenshot:

Answer (score 1):

It is under `Applications > Qt Quick Application > Qt Quick Controls X.X`.

Pick a Qt Quick project, and like it says in the description of the one with Qt Quick Controls, it creates a `.ui.qml` file.

[image]

[image]

Hope that helps.